# How to remove a specific compiler warning in CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

CMake seems to append some default compiler flags such as `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and so on when generating a Makefile project. One of those default flags is `-Wsign-conversion` and I would like to remove it from the list. Adding the suppression flag `-Wno-sign-conversion` like so

```
target_compile_options(myTarget PRIVATE "-Wno-sign-conversion")
```

doesn't have any effect. What's the "modern CMake" way of doing this?

Comment: I just checked with CMake 3.20 and it doesn't set any warning flags by default. The flags it sets are "-g" for debug builds and "-O3 -DNDEBUG" for release builds. I remember that there recently was a series of changes to reduce the number of default flags, so maybe your version of CMake is too old. But I think it is more likely that your own project or something you include adds the warning flags (e.g. the toolchain file if you have one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to query for the compiler ID/name and/or version (which quickly becomes a mess) you can use [CheckCCompilerFlag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCCompilerFlag.html) (or [CheckCXXCompilerFlag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXCompilerFlag.html)). The trick here is to not check for the warning disable flag, but for the warning itself. For example:

```
include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
check_c_compiler_flag(-Wsign-conversion HAVE_SIGN_CONVERSION)

if (HAVE_SIGN_CONVERSION)
    target_compile_options(target_name PRIVATE -Wno-sign-conversion)
endif (HAVE_SIGN_CONVERSION)
```

As a side note, it is recommended to avoid setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and/or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly. If possible, please use `target_compile_options` to disable the warning only for the targets for which you need to do this. If you want to globally disable it use `add_compile_options`.

Note that if other parts of your build scripts set these flags directly you may still get the warning (for example, if someone does `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wsign-conversion")`). This is one of the reasons for which you should avoid setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly - it becomes extremely hard to control what happens.

The order in which the options are added also matters. The following minimal examples illustrates things (assuming that `example.cpp` contains code that will trigger a `-Wsign-conversion` warning):

```
project(example)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE -Wsign-conversion)
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE -Wno-sign-conversion)
```

This will suppress the warning. The compiler is invoked like this: `/usr/bin/c++    -Wsign-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion`

We can swap the two `target_compile_options` calls:

```
project(example)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE -Wno-sign-conversion)
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE -Wsign-conversion)
```

In this case, the compiler is invoked like this: `/usr/bin/c++    -Wno-sign-conversion -Wsign-conversion` and triggers the warning.

Comment: Just to add to this: These compiler checks have non-negligible overhead when configuring the project. So if you know that every GCC and Clang version that your project supports (e.g. if you require C++20 features only available in versions that have the warning) it is better to check for the compiler id instead.

Comment: This is true, but you usually configure the project once. It may still impact your CI build times, so it's worth thinking about, but I'll personally take the longer configure time instead of nested if/else for compiler ID and version (personal opinion, there's no right thing to do, depends heavily on your use case and priorities).

Comment: The problem here, as in my original example, is that if `HAVE_SIGN_CONVERSION == true` and then you add the disable flag, you would end up with something like this in the Makefile: `... -Wall -Wextra ... -Wsign-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion`. Adding the `-no` version of any warning flag seem to be ineffective in GCC if the corresponding "positive" flag has already been set.

Comment: If you have the warnings in this order they should not be triggered: `-Wsign-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion`. `-Wconversion` also enables `-Wsign-conversion`, can you check if that flag isn't enabled after you disable `-Wsign-conversion`?

Comment: You can also use generator expressions instead of nested if/elses: `add_compile_options($<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GCC>:-Wno-sign-conversion> $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/w4012>)` 

Of course it is always a tradeoff, but I recently patched several 3rdparty projects that we build from source as part of our own build to not do these kind of checks and shaved off 30s of configuration time on Windows. These quickly add up.

Comment: @icebp good point. After looking further into the Makefile, those warnings in my case are generated in the wrong order: `... -Wno-sign-conversion ... -Wsign-conversion`. BTW no trace of `-Wconversion` anywhere.

Comment: It should work if you change the order. I don't if CMake makes any guarantees regarding the order in which the options are passed to the compiler, but I think a lot of things will break if flags are passed in a random order. So maybe the flag is enabled after you disable it?

Comment: "So maybe the flag is enabled after you disable it?" Yes, looks like you are on the right track. Also, as @Corristo suggested, those flags might be added by a dependency included by the main project. I need to look into this further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is "modern CMake" but I use something like this to set the gcc flags, directly after the cmake_minimum_required Variable.

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-sign-conversion")
endif()
```