# How to disable implicit conversion changes signedness warning in CMAKE

Tags: c++, unsigned, suppress-warnings, size-t

Does anybody know if there is a way to disable this kind of warning given by clang in CMAKE please ?

```
std::vector<float> v{1.f, 2.f, 1.f};
int i = 1;
float foo = v[i]; // Here we get the warning, variable i should be a size_t

...

Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'std::__1::vector<float>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

Clang compiler gives me a warning on `v[i]` as it wants me to cast it as a `size_t` which is quite verbose if I do explicit casting everywhere.

Also, I don't want to use `size_t`. For me this type it is error prone as it breaks the standard substraction when getting negative results. (my vectors will never exceed 2^31 btw)

Comment: _as it wants me to cast it as a `size_t` ..._ Why not simply use `size_t i = 1u;` in 1st place?

Comment: You say that now. A few years on you might have vectors with 2^31 elements.

Comment: Don't suppress the warnings, they are your friend.  Instead fix the code.  That said, if you really want to suppress the warning, I think you need `-Wno-sign-conversion`

Comment: I recommend using gsl::index from https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/#Readme

Comment: Because size_t is overkill for my usage. I never got overflow pbs with standard int. On the opposite, size_t is tricky with negative numbers and I have already got fooled many times with comparison that is broken when the value wrap to the max. Also, int are faster than size_t as the wrapping property reduce the optimisations opportunities.

Comment: I tried target_compile_options(DRM PROJECTNAME "-Wno-sign-conversion") but it didn't work unfortunatly.

Comment: What compiler are you targetting?

Comment: I'm targetting Xcode/Clang

Comment: The signedness of sizes and subscripts has been (and will be) longly [debated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1428r0.pdf). Can you avoid indices at all in your code by using proper algorithms (therefore iterators or views)?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. As it is so much debated, I would except there would be solutions. I'm just dealing yet with +999 warnings waiting for a fix in next versions of C++ like ssize() which is already a first step. But I would be glad to be able to mute the warnings already, as this warning is harmless for my usage.

Comment: Have you already tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297878/how-to-remove-a-specific-compiler-warning-in-cmake ?